# Can we convert a Python project (and not a string) to binaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this folder for a Python project:

```
Project
     __main__.py
     main.py
     utils.py
```

And I want to convert those files into binaries and move them to a 'bin' folder, then convert them to an executable Windows and Linux files, but I don't know that if we convert it to an executable file without converting the Python files, the users need to install Python.

Comment: There are multiple ways to convert a python project to an executable. Searching "python to exe" yields good results.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't think you understand, I want first to convert the python files into binaries.

Comment: Do you mean the `pyc` files storing the byte code that CPython generates from Python source code?

Comment: No, in like, .o file extension @chepner

Comment: That would just be a Python compiler that targets x86-64, ARM, etc, instead of Python byte code. Such a program would not be considerably simpler than just an existing CPython interpreter that reads the byte code.

Comment: Several (most if not all) of the existing solutions for converting a Python programs into into .exes do so in such a way that Python doesn't have to be installed on target computers in order to run them.